# Cant get circular progress bar to display when using ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

Currently I'm trying to get the custom ring progress bars to display properly on an android sdk level 23 and below. They work perfectly on android SDK 25+.

Im using a custom library for circular progress bars found here: https://github.com/HotBitmapGG/RingProgressBar, above android lolipop, the layout looks like this:

[SDK 23+](https://i.gyazo.com/aeb8b69c824e94db3f280e0def612dce.png)

however on android lolipop  the scrollView seen below breaks the rings so that they dont show up:

[android SDK <23](https://i.gyazo.com/b452b443b550fc9cde5e7676a39b5adb.png)

If i remove the scroll view below the progress bars they start working again and I have no idea why that is so. Also if I call View.GONE() on one of the relative layouts the Rings show up again. I'm fairly certain this is because the scrollView is not being used as everything fits on the screen.
Here is my XML: (the middle section is pretty repetative)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    >

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <ScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/Background"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:fillViewport="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/Background"

            >



            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/Toolbar_Height"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>






            <!--Average-->
            <RelativeLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                tools:context=".Average"

                android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutAverage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@color/Background"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="50dp"
                android:paddingStart="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/Average_Row_Height"
                >


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/AverageText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_mono"
                    android:text="@string/Average"
                    android:textColor="@color/AverageTextColor"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"

                    />


                <io.netopen.hotbitmapgg.library.view.RingProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/AverageBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="115dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/AverageText"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:elevation="15dp"
                    app:max="101"
                    app:ringDiameter="115"
                    app:ringColor="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:ringProgressColor="@color/AverageBarColor"
                    app:ringWidth="12dp"
                    app:style="STROKE"
                    app:textColor="@color/TextColor"
                    app:textIsShow="false"
                    app:textSize="26sp" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/AverageInt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/AverageText"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/TextColor"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </RelativeLayout>


            <!--Ta buttons-->



<!--Button 1-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg_rectangle_solid"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/Row_Height"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Period"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_mono"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="Period 1:"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/SecondaryTextColor"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/RoomNumber"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/Period"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_mono"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/TextColor"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/EmptyCourse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/RoomNumber"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"

                    />


                <io.netopen.hotbitmapgg.library.view.RingProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/SubjectBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    app:max="101"
                    app:ringColor="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:ringDiameter="90"
                    app:ringProgressColor="@color/BarColor1"
                    app:ringWidth="9dp"
                    app:style="STROKE"
                    app:textColor="@color/TextColor"
                    app:textIsShow="false"
                    app:textSize="16sp" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/SubjectInt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@id/SubjectBar"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/TextColor"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/SubjectAbrv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/TextColor"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/SubjectName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/SubjectAbrv"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@id/SubjectAbrv"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/SecondaryTextColor"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />
            </RelativeLayout>

<!--The same thing repeated another 3 times below......-->


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

If anyone knows why this happens id love to know! Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove recurring namespace declaration from your scrollview and relative layout as you dont need them again. try clean and build after that.

Comment: actually similar issue is registered here. https://github.com/HotBitmapGG/RingProgressBar/issues/11

Comment: apply android:fitsSystemWindows="true"  to scroll view and check

Comment: No Luck with either unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Nvm found a workarround. For those that are having the same problem: hardcoding the android:layout_height to a specific dp value should solve the problem.